# ValueError at /basic_app/register/

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

**The view basic_app.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**
***...  Please Help me I am tired to solve or find out this error even couldn't understand this that where it's located*** 
**The view basic_app.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# from django.http import HttpResponse
from basic_app.forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'basic_app/index.html')


def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

                profile.save()

                registered = True

            else:
                print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

        else:
            user_form = UserForm()
            profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

        return render(request, 'basic_app/registration.html',
                      {'user_form': user_form,
                       'profile_form': profile_form,
                       'registered': registered})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    # user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User,models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    # additional
    profile_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**

```
    from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from basic_app.models import UserProfileInfo


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')


class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('profile_site', 'profile_pic')
```

Comment: you are returning an HTTP response in your post method but not in your get method. your View does not handle GET requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dedented your else block. Please check.

```
def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

                profile.save()

                registered = True

            else:
                print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(request, 'basic_app/registration.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form,
                   'profile_form': profile_form,
                   'registered': registered})
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:  # corrected from meta() to Meta
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')


class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:  # corrected from meta() to Meta
        model = UserProfileInfo
```

Comment: ModelForm has no model class specified.

Comment: here is my forms.py file
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from basic_app.models import UserProfileInfo


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')


class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('profile_site', 'profile_pic')

Comment: @Rasel edit your Question and put contents of forms.py into Question description.